# Trying to use Sha 256 to generate a random hash and assign it to a variable but getting command not found when checking its value

Tags: bash, shell

When i do

```
echo User1 | sha256sum
```

i get

```
63085ad94a3278338ca12c823f49a8494454e6728a28e20cf79a1b685ddeaad9  -
```

but when i do

```
User1=$(echo User1 | sha256sum)
```

and then

```
$User1
```

i get

```
bash: 63085ad94a3278338ca12c823f49a8494454e6728a28e20cf79a1b685ddeaad9: command not found
```

any reason why i get the bash and command not found and not just the hash? Im looking to assign the hash to the variable

Answer (score 2):

`$User1` says to execute whatever's in the `User1` variable and since `63085ad94...` probably isn't the name of a valid command the error message `command not found` is generated.

If the intent is to *display* the contents of the variable then consider ...

```
$ echo "$User1"
63085ad94a3278338ca12c823f49a8494454e6728a28e20cf79a1b685ddeaad9 -

$ typeset -p User1
declare -- User1="63085ad94a3278338ca12c823f49a8494454e6728a28e20cf79a1b685ddeaad9 -"

$ printf "%s\n" "$User1"
63085ad94a3278338ca12c823f49a8494454e6728a28e20cf79a1b685ddeaad9 -
```